# How to find the largest duplicate of a list python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Given a list of positive integers, associate the largest duplicated element with the variable `maximum`. If the list contains no duplicates, associate -1 with `maximum`.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one way to do it, depending on your time/space complexity requirements. Here're some ideas:

**Using a set**

```
def max_dup(lst):
    seen = set()        
    for i in sorted(lst, reverse=True):
        if i in seen:
            return i
        seen.add(i)
    return -1
```

**Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)**

```
from collections import Counter

def max_dup(lst):
    cnt = Counter(lst)
    return max((k for k in cnt if cnt[k] > 1), default=-1)
```

**Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)**

```
from itertools import groupby

def max_dup(lst):
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(lst, reverse=True)):
        if len(list(g)) > 1:
            return k
    return -1
```

In my tests (for rather small lists) using a set appears to be the fastest method, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: There is a [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.

Comment: @taras: How would it help to find the _largest duplicate_?

Comment: agree. I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without counters too:

```
def max_dup(numbers):
    desc_numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
    for i in range(1, len(desc_numbers)):
        if desc_numbers[i] == desc_numbers[i - 1]:
            return desc_numbers[i]
    return -1

print(max_dup([1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7])) # 5
print(max_dup([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])) # -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with *itertools.groupby* we would first have to sort our list, and then we could take only `k` if its corresponding `list(g)` has a `len > 1` into a new list. We could then use `max` on that list

```
from itertools import groupby
lista = [1, 5, 3, 4, 1, 5, 7]
max_dup = -1

lrg_dup = [k for k, g in groupby(sorted(lista)) if len(list(g)) > 1]
if lrg_dup:
    max_dup = max(lrg_dup)
# 5
```

Expanded:

```
lrg_dup = []
listb = sorted(lista)
for k, g in groupby(listb):
    if len(list(g)) > 1:
        lrg_dup.append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list, iterate through the list in pairs, exit on first matching pair.

```
def maxdup(l):
    l = sorted(l, reverse=True)
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[i-1] == l[i]:
            return l[i]

    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this line to iterate over the list

```
return lst.count(max(lst)) if lst.count(max(lst)) > 0 else -1
```